# how do I format curl within laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am trying to make a curl request like below within laravel

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer xxx" -X POST -H 'Tus-Resumable: 1.0.0' -H 'Upload-Length: 900000000' 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/xxx/stream?direct_user=true'
```

I tried this in my controller

```
public function createVideo(){
        
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/xxx/stream/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"maxDurationSeconds\": 3600}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = ['direct_user'=>'true'];  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxx';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {     
   $error_msg = curl_error($ch); 
   echo $error_msg; 
} 

$url = json_decode($result)->result->uploadURL;

 return view('school.createvideo')->with('url',$url);
    }
```

but I get this error

ErrorException
Trying to get property 'uploadURL' of non-object

Comment: The specific error means your `$result` does not contain `->result`, or in the form you expect. Do some `var_dump()` for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can do everything yourself with cURL, using an HTTP Client simplifies things enormously, particularly when it comes to debugging. So, instead of using cURL directly, you could just use an HTTP Client instead.

Laravel comes with a built-in [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/http-client). Using that you can do something like:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'bearer xxx',
    'Tus-Resumable' => 1.0.0,
    'Upload-Length' => 900000000
])->post('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/xxx/stream?direct_user=true');

return $response->body();
```

Comment: ok trying to work it out with the HTTP Client